# Xcode 7.0.1 error - dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib

Tags: xcode, swift, certificate

This question has been asked before in different guises.
Just upgraded to to 7.0.1 and now get.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D6FBEFBE-C7BA-4680-97F3-701F110C6C9A/S123.app/S123
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D6FBEFBE-C7BA-4680-97F3-701F110C6C9A/S123.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D6FBEFBE-C7BA-4680-97F3-701F110C6C9A/S123.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
(lldb)
```

Program compiles but crashes on the load screen.
Usual approaches have been tried:

- Restarting computer/iPhone
- Deleted App on iPhone
- Created new certificate
- Check rogue entry in Packaging

A lot of people seem to have had problems with this. Is it the Cert?

Comment: Just had this problem yesterday, I think i resolved it with removing some certificates, try removing all of them (development and production), and requesting new ones.

Comment: Do certificates work immediately or is there a time delay between submission and being able to use them?

Comment: They should work immediately.

Comment: Apologies for being thick here but I can't work out how to import a regenerated (new) profile into Xcode 7.0.1. I can find lots of 2013 references but the menus seem to have been changed. Suspect this is the solution as you suggested but can't find the procedure to implement it.

Comment: Go to your Keychain Access, and delete them there